# Controller chaining in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

```
/**
 * Created with JetBrains WebStorm.
 * User: Faizan
 * Date: 3/7/14
 * Time: 6:09 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("CtrlParent",function($scope){
      $scope.ParentFunc= function(){
          alert("This is Parent");
         // $scope.$on("hello");
      }
    })
.controller('CtrlBigChild',function($scope){
        $scope.BigChildFunc= function(){
            alert("This is Big Child");
           // $scope.$on("hello");
        }
    })
.controller('CtrlChildOne',function($scope){
        $scope.ChildOneFunc= function(){
            alert("This is Child One");
         //   $scope.$on("hello");
        }
    })
.controller('CtrlChildTwo',function($scope){
        $scope.CtrlChildTwoFunc= function(){
            alert("This is Child Two");
          //  $scope.$on("hello");
        }
})
.controller('CtrlChildOneChild',function ($scope){
        $scope.ChildOneChildFunc= function(){
            alert("This is Child one's Child");
         //   $scope.$on("hello");
        }
    })
.controller('CtrlChildTwoChild',function($scope){
        $scope.ChildTwoChildFunc= function(){
            alert("This is Child Two's Child");
        //    $scope.$on("hello");

        }
    })
```

1: Failed to load resource file:///C:/Users/Faizan/WebstormProjects/AngularJS%20emit%20broadcase%20controller/js/controller.js.js

2 :Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.10/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…rJS%2520emit%2520broadcase%2520controller%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A431)

Comment: Use server, `http://`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are referencing the correct module in ng-app.
`<body ng-app="myApp">`

[This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wittwerj/txGc2/) contains your code, and produces no errors.

You can reproduce error 2 by changing ng-app (under fiddle options) to something else like:
`<body ng-app="banana">`

---

And, make sure that you reference angular before your javascript filess, such as controller.js.

Comment: i have chekcked still facing Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined controller.js:9
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.10/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…rJS%2520emit%2520broadcase%2520controller%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A431)

Comment: reference to angular must be before your controller.js file.

Comment: great, i added that suggestion to the answer.